# ReadAsync - thread exited with code 259

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, windows-phone-8, bluetooth

I have problems with bluetooth connection. It is endless connection and after several seconds it is always hangs up on ReadAsync with information:

> The thread 0x19c has exited with code 259 (0x103). 
>   The program '[5612] TaskHost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

After this - connection is still valid with device (I see connection diode on device), but there is no chance to: 
1) Connect again to device (connection is still present) 
2) Receive any data from socket/connection

It is allways hanging here:

```
   returnedBuffer =
                await
                    socket.InputStream.ReadAsync(buffer.AsBuffer(), (uint)buffer.Length,
                        InputStreamOptions.Partial);
```

Modyfied code is from 32feet sample:

```
    private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var bdp = new BluetoothDevicePicker();
        PeerInformation pi = await bdp.PickDeviceAsync();
        if (pi != null)
        {
            var hn = new HostName(pi.HostName.RawName);

            // do something with the device
            ReadThread(hn);
        }
    }

    private async void ReadThread(object host)
{
    reading = true;

    var socket = new StreamSocket();
    socket.Control.KeepAlive = true;
    socket.Control.NoDelay = false;
    //socket.Control.QualityOfService = SocketQualityOfService.LowLatency;

    IAsyncAction a = StreamSocketExtensions.ConnectAsync(socket, (HostName)host, RfcommServiceId.SerialPort);
    await a;

    var buffer = new byte[2048];

    while (reading)
    {
        IBuffer returnedBuffer = null;
        try
        {
            returnedBuffer =
                await
                    socket.InputStream.ReadAsync(buffer.AsBuffer(), (uint)buffer.Length,
                        InputStreamOptions.Partial);
            if (returnedBuffer != null)
            {

                string s = PrintByteArray(returnedBuffer.ToArray(), (int)returnedBuffer.Length);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                {


                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<string>(InsertMessage), s);


                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }

    }

    socket.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Side note: don't add tags to title of the post and instead of adding signature edit user name.